# Can 1,782 cM shared indicate Half Siblings?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis, half-siblings

Could a person with 1,782 cM actually be my half-sibling?

This person is listed as close family to me, yet I do not know them.

My cM is the same as this person's.

I do have 6 paternal half siblings however.

Answer (score 2):

[DNAPainter](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1782) suggests several possible relationships for 1782cm shared DNA.

I suspect that some of them you can rule out immediately (grandparent, for example).

But yes, half-sibling is one of the possibilities.

Comment: Thank you! This person was adopted. Doesn't know anything about either parent but I suspect, since I know my bio dad's history, that I may have another sibling.